# Can I drink this ? Hard cider rack leftovers

Tags: cider, racking

I just racked my hard cider. There is leftover liquid with lees now and I was wonder if that can be filtered and drank. Any thoughts ?

Comment: You probably CAN drink it, the question is rather, is it any good?

Answer (score 2):

No reason why not.  It's just cider.  Though the lees will give you some weird flavors.  And bad gas.

Comment: Or cook with it.

Comment: I concur with Tobias.  Fry up some shallots, garlic, and the whites of leeks.  Season with salt and pepper.  Pour in your lees to braise the leeks, a couple sprigs of thyme, and a tbsp or two of butter.  Reduce the liquid down (15-20 minutes), turning the leeks, then crush up some hazelnuts.  Once reduced, pull out the leeks, sprinkle the hazelnuts over with some freshly chopped coriander and you have yourself the best leeks side dish you'll ever taste!  Wait...  This isn't the cooking stack exchange?  Sorry, got ahead of myself...  Also, the lees will serve well to deglaze your pans.

Comment: Cooking with the yeasty lees doesn't sound very appealing does it?

Answer (score 0):

Any leftover "suds" is just as alcoholic as what you've racked, but lacks carbonation.  You can drank it, but it will be a flat version of whatever will come out of the bottles/keg in a week or two.

Personally, I've put the left over liquid from beer brewing over ice to get an advanced taste of what my brew will be like, and to make sure it wasn't infected.  Its not as enjoyable as the finished product, but still drinkable in small quantities.